# Asphalt or concrete, which job first?

Tags: concrete, asphalt, sidewalk

I have an asphalt driveway with a concrete sidewalk meeting the edge of it. They both need to be replaced. Which job needs to happen first?

Comment: If the concrete comes second then you're patching holes in the asphalt made by the forms. The driveway would need to have something be mission critical about it, to do it out of order. Not that it *needs* to, but it *should*.

Comment: Do they lie side-by-side, or does one lie under the other?

Answer (score 40):

I would have the driveway and sidewalk both removed at the same time so you're not removing one next to a finished product. Then have the sidewalk installed. After the forms are removed and the sidewalk cured, install the asphalt. It can be installed and compacted right up to the edge of the sidewalk and made level with it if that's how you want it.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. ++++    Much easier to "trim out".  Not only that, you don't want heavy cement trucks on fresh asphalt. Besides, it would be really hard to get a clean edge where the asphalt and sidewalk would meet.   Def, JACK is right, sidewalks/concrete first.

Answer (score 18):

I have to post this as an answer because I know I won't have enough space for a comment.

Last year I managed a pretty large driveway/replacement project for my mother's house.  I was a large (and I mean LARGE) circular driveway and other substantial driveway sections.  It was 70 years old and in dire need of replacement.     We originally thought asphalt,  I personally knew the asphalt guy and he said you might consider concrete for the entire job. Due to oil prices and the base that would have to be installed (quarry spall and crushed rock), not to mention the excavation and disposal expenses, he said concrete might be less expensive. Asphalt needs a very good base because it's not that strong.

So we went with concrete for the entire job, replaced a couple of sidewalks and made them level with the new driveway, which is great bc mom uses a walker and now she  doesn't have any steps to worry about. The entire pour was also reinforced with rebar.

So you might want to be open minded about this and consider design opportunities going all concrete.

Comment: On our house build two years ago concrete was cheaper than asphalt. In my experience, it's more durable too.

Comment: On the other hand, price isn't everything. Concrete has a very different look. Also keep in mind that concrete should be somewhat rough to avoid slipping, further changing the looks.

Comment: It's my understanding (hey, I saw it on the internet, so it has to be right. Right?) that asphalt _requires_ regular vehicle traffic to keep it compacted so it will last longer. Driveways just don't get enough traffic to keep the asphalt in good condition which is why they end up needing sealing every year or two and break down so much more quickly than roads. Concrete, while a different look will last much longer with just the light traffic of a driveway. (Assuming the proper prep for both applications.)

Comment: @FreeMan  I didn't know that about asphalt, good call!   I learn something here almost every day.  Also with concrete, you can get more creative.  Using a stamped concrete approach, we put a boarder, about 8-10" wide along parts of the sidewalk/patio using a grapes/vines pattern for just a touch of bling. Really turned out good.  We didn't stain or seal it bc the contractor said that if we did, we'd have to re-seal every couple of years, but even un-stained, it looks good.

Comment: @Mr47  Exposed aggregate has a great look and will minimize slipping.

Comment: Hmmm, if concrete is cheaper than asphalt, maybe we should go back to it for building roads. I kinda miss the da-dump, da-dump, da-dump sound of the expansion joints from driving on a concrete highway from my youth.

Comment: @GlenYates  Nearly all the major highways, freeways, interstates are made of concrete.  Here in western Washington state, they've been working on a "revive I-5" project for years and all the pavement is concrete.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson I drove I-5 from somewhere south of Everett to SeaTac earlier this year and I don't remember whether any of it was concrete.

Comment: @GlenYates  It's just about all concrete.   I-5 is the major north-south route here and asphalt just can't stand up to the constant heavy traffic.

Comment: @Mr47  Note that concrete can have colorants and a wide range of types of sand, gravel and other fillers added, modifying the appearance.

Comment: Stamped concrete can be done in a huge variety of patterns as well as colorings as @Technophile said.   A combination of stamped, stained concrete and exposed aggregate is a pretty high end look.  Google it and you'll find tons of idea.   This is a design opportunity!

Comment: All the stuff about I-5 is off topic.  Standing up to constant traffic is not important for a driveway.  It may still be better to use concrete for the whole job, but major freeways are not an argument for that.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson Exposed aggregate loos great and does help with slipping but if you live in an area with a lot of snow, it can be a pain if it's too rough e.g. it tears up shovels and blower slides.  If you get your driveway plowed, it could tear up the surface as well.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson another negative for exposed aggregate is that, for those with mobility issues, traversing exposed aggregate is like offroading in a Ford Focus.